# Properly formatting Invoke-RestMethod results?

Tags: powershell, scripting, sendgrid

Here's my code:

```
$token = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx'
$uri = "https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/teammates?limit=500&offset=0"
$subuser = Read-Host "Enter the Subuser value"
$headers1 = @{"Authorization" = "Bearer $token" 
    "on-behalf-of" = "$subuser"
}

Do {
    Write-Host "Do you know the teammates username? Y/N" -ForegroundColor Yellow
    $response = Read-Host
}
While ($response.ToLower() -notin "y", "n")

Switch ($response.ToLower())
{
    "y" {
        $username = Read-host "Enter Username"
        $apiurl = $uri + $username
        $data = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri $apiurl -headers $headers1
        break
    }
    "n" {
        $uri = $uri 
        $data = Invoke-RestMethod -method GET -uri $uri -headers $headers1 
        
        break
    }
}
$data | convertto-json
```

So the value of `$results` is:

```
{
    "result":  [
                   {
                       "username":  "ben.michael",
                       "email":  "ben.michael@company.com",
                       "first_name":  "Ben",
                       "last_name":  "Michael",
                       "address":  "",
                       "address2":  "",
                       "city":  "",
                       "state":  "",
                       "zip":  "",
                       "country":  "",
                       "company":  "",
                       "website":  "",
                       "phone":  "",
                       "is_admin":  false,
                       "is_sso":  false,
                       "user_type":  "teammate"
                   },
                   {
                       "username":  "brandon.nosk",
                       "email":  "brandon.nosk@company.com",
                       "first_name":  "Brandon",
                       "last_name":  "Nosk",
                       "address":  "",
                       "address2":  "",
                       "city":  "",
                       "state":  "",
                       "zip":  "",
                       "country":  "",
                       "company":  "",
                       "website":  "",
                       "phone":  "",
                       "is_admin":  false,
                       "is_sso":  false,
                       "user_type":  "teammate"
                   },
```

What I need to do is being able `Format-Table username, email` But since this is a `PSCustomObject` I can't figure out the proper method.  If I drop the `ConvertTo-JSON` then the value of `$results` is:

```
result                                                                                                                      
------                                                                                                                      
{@{username=ben.michael; email=ben.michael@comapny.com; first_name=Ben; last_name=Michael; address=; address2=; ci..
```

which I think is a hashtable but I'm not positive. I'm desperately seeking help to parse the username and email values...

Comment: When you type `$results`, output shows you that value of `$results` is an object with single a field named `result`. So, to use it, use `$results.result | FT -Property @('username', 'email')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code doesn't show you capture the output in `$results`, but you can simply output

```
$data.result | Select-Object username, email
```

Right above the `break` s in the switch.

Next, **remove** `$data | convertto-json`

Comment: I think this should be `$data.result | Select username, email`

Comment: @user19702 Ah, yes.. my bad. I have edited now. Thanks!

Comment: Holy crap... I tried all sorts of variations on $data.xxxx but why 'results', So simple of a fix. Thank you so much!  But why is it returning all the data underneath the word results?